# Use Parameter with no need of creating stored procedures

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to use or add parameters on a simple query without the need of creating stored procedures or function?  Are [Bind Variables](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html) possible without creating a stored procedures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

where are you running the code from? If your running from a language like Java / VB you would use a stored procedure or prepared statement.

If using from Sql *Plus terminal or other Sql UI

```
SQL> variable deptno number 
SQL> exec :deptno := 10 
SQL> select * from
    emp where deptno = :deptno;
```

From a high level language like Java or VB use stored procedures, following is from the article you linked to so not sure why you are asking this?

> In fact, the answer to this is actually quite simple. When you put
>   together an SQL statement using Java, or VB, or whatever, you usually
>   use an API for accessing the database; ADO in the case of VB, JDBC in
>   the case of Java. All of these APIs have built-in support for bind
>   variables, and it's just a case of using this support rather than just
>   concatenating a string yourself and submitting it to the database.
>
> For example, Java has PreparedStatement, which allows the use of bind
>   variables, and Statement, which uses the string concatenation
>   approach. If you use the method that supports bind variables, the API
>   itself passes the bind variable value to Oracle at runtime, and you
>   just submit your SQL statement as normal. There's no need to
>   separately pass the bind variable value to Oracle, and actually no
>   additional work on your part. Support for bind variables isn't just
>   limited to Oracle - it's common to other RDBMS platforms such as
>   Microsoft SQL Server, so there's no excuse for not using them just
>   because they might be an Oracle-only feature.

Not sure why you are asking as this information is there on the site http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming you will perform queries using an external programming language, prepared statements will make the job.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement